# I have a new UIViewController and new class, but I can't associate the two in Xcode 10

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I've added a new View Controller to my storyboard.  I've added a new Cocoa Touch Class .swift file and subclassed UIViewController.  I select the new UIViewController in the storyboard and click the identify panel, but my new subclass OptionViewController doesn't show up in the dropdown.

I've done a Clean Build Folder.  I've done a successful BUILD. Still no love.

```swift
class OptionsViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
```

etc.

[image: dropdown]

Comment: Maybe the target wasn't set correctly when you created the file.

Comment: I select the new file.  Look at the inspector and it lists the same target that the other custom subclasses show.

Comment: Just type the name yourself and hit Return. What happens?

Comment: I'm able to type in the name.  It never autocompletes, nor suggests the class name.  I can create a link from the main view controller TABController to the new view  It compiles. But a debug print statement in the OptionsViewController class viewDidLoad() never prints when I click the screen's icon in the tab controller

Comment: Can you post the project for download? Easiest just to look at it and try to see what’s wrong.

Comment: Found the problem.  Some sort of corruption within Xcode that didn't get swept away with a Clean Build Folder.  I quit Xcode entirely.  Started it up.  Build.  Run.  It works.  The OptionsViewController class's viewDidLoad() is getting executed and I can see the debug message appearing in the console.  Thanks to all who provided input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corruption.  Exited Xcode and restarted it.